# How to do list to grid animated transition in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, animation, css-transitions

How to implement animated list to grid transition in HTML, using Twitter Bootstrap? So when you toggle between list and grid it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: you could use css animations and switch between list & grid classes.

Comment: @ZimSystem yes, I've tried MixItUp plugin, http://mixitup.kunkalabs.com, haven't managed to work it with Bootstrap so far

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS transition like this. You'd need to tweak the animation.

```
.row div {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/7GHR01JOez

Comment: this doesn't work in my browser(Safari, Chrome), just blinks and shows a bunch of grid cells